# what's the use of greater/less then sign in Objective-C <>

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi what's the use of < > in ios? I can't find some documentation of that.

Here's an example of it's use

> id < TYPE >

I hope someone can help me with my problem. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: In Objective C or Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it's a generic object pointer that conforms to the specified protocol.

Therefore:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)someMethod:(int)a;
@end

@interface SomeClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol>

@end
```

Would allow:

```
SomeClass *obj = [SomeClass new];

// call method via the protocol interface
id<SomeProtocol> iface = obj;
[iface someMethod:1];
```

Answer (score 3):

It indicates that a class adopts a protocol (specified within the '<>')

See apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/workingwithprotocols/workingwithprotocols.html

By the way, it is a language feature rather than an OS one. You should label your question as `objective-c` rather than `iOS`

Answer (score 2):

It's part of a class definition (`@interface`) or a type defining a variable. Its a way of telling the compiler thatthe class/type implements a protocol. The name of the protocols the class implements are inside the triangular brackets separated by commas.

In your case:

```
id <protocolName> object;
```

Means that you are declaring a variable called `object` of type `id` that implements the protocol `protocolName`.

A protocol is a collection of methods. So it allows you to send messages defined by `protocolName` to `object` without the compiler issuing warnings.

Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/workingwithprotocols/workingwithprotocols.html).